# Issue with IF and AND Statement for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to put together a bit of code to result in a yes or no.

Basically if all cells result in Yes then it outputs yes if not No.

I have this working exactly how i need it to:

=IF(AND(Y4="Yes",V4="Yes",S4="Yes",P4="Yes",M4="Yes",J4="Yes",G4="Yes",D4="Yes"),"Yes", "No")

But in some cases V4 can be blank and even if it's blank I'd like it to stil output as "Yes". How can i do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: welcome to SuperUser :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to bring an OR into it:

```
=IF(AND(Y4="Yes",S4="Yes",P4="Yes",M4="Yes",J4="Yes",G4="Yes",D4="Yes"(OR(V4="Yes", V4="")),"Yes", "No")
```

Comment: Hi @PeterH , this needs little correction `=IF(AND(OR(Y4="",Y4="Yes"),OR(V4="",V4="Yes"),OR(S4="",S4="Yes")),"Yes", "No")` !!

Comment: Thanks guys i think we're nearly there:

=IF(AND(OR(Y4="",Y4="Yes"),OR(V4="",V4="Yes"),OR(S4="",S4="Yes")),"Yes", "No")

It only needs to be V4 which can be either Yes or "" (blank), all the other values need to be "Yes". How would I add in all the other cells M4, G4, D4 etc

Comment: Would something like this work?
=IF(AND(Y4="Yes",S4="Yes",P4="Yes",M4="Yes",J4="Yes",G4="Yes",D4="Yes"(OR(V4="Yes", V4="")),"Yes", "No")

Comment: @RajeshS thanks Raj, will teach me for not actually trying it out in excel !

Comment: @JoshuaSadler play around with removing the ORs etc and adding extra criteria to the AND, the best way to learn is by trying it out yourself ;)

Comment: =IF(AND(Y4="Yes",S4="Yes",P4="Yes",M4="Yes",J4="Yes",G4="Yes",D4="Yes",(OR(V4="Yes", V4="")),"Yes", "No") was just missing one comma @JoshuaSadler but yh spot on

Comment: thanks guys, really great help and learnt something today! Top stuff

Comment: Hi @PeterH,,, I found 1 parenthesis was missing,,, and nothing more,, have wonderful weekend ☺

Answer (score 1):

*Instead of multiple IF or other logical test, I would like to suggest one smart formula, solves the issue.*

```
 =IF(OR(ISBLANK($Y$4), $Y$4<>"Yes"),"NO",IF(COUNTIF($D$4:$S$4,"=Yes")>0,"YES","NO"))
```

- This formula will first check whether Y4 is either `BLANK` or `Not Equals to YES`, then returns **NO**, in case Y4 has Yes then returns **YES**.
- Next check the second IF, and return **YES**, if any of cells from D4 to
  S4 has `Yes`.
- Returns **NO**, if all are either `BLANK` or has text other than `Yes`.

---

**N.B.**

- **In case if you would like to check cells in random order then you
  need to go with Nested IF and Logical test.**
- In that case you may go with this one:

  =IF(OR(ISBLANK($Y$4), $Y$4<>"Yes"),"NO",IF(OR(D4="Yes",J4="Yes",P4="Yes"),"YES","NO"))
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.